# How to catch action from Facebook 'Like' button

Tags: facebook, dom-events, facebook-like

Is there a way to catch event of clicking Facebook like button? I don't want to integrate my app with Facebook, just need to count clicks of 'Like'. Tried :

```
$('.fb_iframe_widget').click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
});
```

but without any luck. If there is no way of doing this will I be able to count likes of particular pages when synced with FB API ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use the xfbml like button rather than the iframe button. After you switch that, do the following:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // user clicked like button!
});
```

The facebook event "edge.create" is called when a like button is clicked. I have no idea why it is named that, but that will do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, then I think you'd be out of luck, as you can't do anything else because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).